Never-ending QuickCheck test leaves running process even after interrupting "cabal test"
Take this silly test, which is meant to never terminate:
module Main where

import Control.Monad (unless)
import System.Exit (exitFailure)
import Test.QuickCheck

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- quickCheckResult neverEnding
  unless (isSuccess result) exitFailure

neverEnding :: [Int] -> Bool
neverEnding [] = True
neverEnding ls = let ls' = cycle ls
                 in 10 == sum ls'

Since I'm in a Cabal project, I can run it via
$ cabal test

Upon doing so, I get this:
Build profile: -w ghc-9.4.8 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - xnobar-0.1.0.0 (test:Test) (first run)
Preprocessing test suite 'Test' for xnobar-0.1.0.0..
Building test suite 'Test' for xnobar-0.1.0.0..
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite Test: RUNNING...

It's apparent it's not returning, so I Ctrl+c.
Afterwards, the executable is still running:
$ pidof Test
425742

and, after a few moments, my ears will realize it too.
So I have to go and kill it myself:
kill $(pidof Test)

which results in
Test suite Test: FAIL
Test suite logged to:
/path/to/Test.log
0 of 1 test suites (0 of 1 test cases) passed.


Now, I'm not certainly writing non-terminating tests intentionally, but I have definitely done it by mistake, and having a process run wild, detached from the cabal test that lauches it, feels just wrong, and as far as possible from what I would expect when working in a Haskell environment.
Is my set up wrong or it's just how Cabal+QuickCheck play together and I have to live with it?

That sounds like a bug in cabal

I opened an issue https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/9913
